# Storing bash output into a variable using eval

Tags: bash

I have a line of code

```
eval echo \$$var
```

which prints a string.  How can I store this string into a variable?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like this:

```
eval c=\$$var
```

a better, safer way is to use indirection:

```
c=${!var}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been struggling to do a variable-variable in bourne shell for good few hours. The later option here is listed lots of places but only works in `bash`, but the former also works in `sh`.

Comment: neither works: bad substitution for the latter. bash 4.4.23

Comment: I think it's the value of var that causes the bad substitution error. Try with valid names.

Answer (score 27):

```
newVariable=$(eval echo \$$var)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it results in the value having a dollar sign as the first character? I tried \$var, but then the variables in my string are not expanded anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: `\` is the escape char, if you put it before a `$` you definitely end up with it. Try `$var`. Or use the 2nd example in the post above.

Comment: In my case I did: `newVariable=$(eval $var)` and worked !

Answer (score 4):

You can try this: It worked for me on bash.

```
c=$(eval echo \${$var})
```

Example: If `HOME` is the environment variable that contains your home directory like `/export/users/john`, then embedding a variable within another variable and then unpacking that combination would work like this:

```
var=HOME
c=$(eval echo \${$var})
echo $c
/export/users/john
```

While this might look unnecessarily convoluted it will be useful in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

This can achieved by using the back quote syntax : `` ` ` ``

```
c=`$var`
```

Comment: this is missing the second tick