# Pass environment variable into a Vue App at runtime

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes

How can I access environment variables in Vue, that are passed to the container at runtime and not during the build?

Stack is as follows:

- VueCLI 3.0.5
- Docker
- Kubernetes

There are suggested solutions on stackoverflow and elsewhere to use .env file to pass variables (and using mode) but that's at build-time and gets baked into the docker image.

I would like to pass the variable into Vue at run-time as follows:

- Create Kubernetes ConfigMap (I get this right)
- Pass ConfigMap value into K8s pod env variable when running deployment yaml file (I get this right)
- Read from env variable created above eg. VUE_APP_MyURL and do something with that value in my Vue App (I DO NOT get this right)

I've tried the following in helloworld.vue:

```
<template>
<div>{{displayURL}}
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {  
    data() {
        return {
            displayURL: ""
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("check 1")
        this.displayURL=process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL
        console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL)
        console.log("check 3")
    }
}
</script>
```

I get back "undefined" in the console log and nothing showing on the helloworld page.

I've also tried passing the value into a vue.config file and reading it from there. Same "undefined" result in console.log

```
<template>
<div>{{displayURL}}
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
const vueconfig = require('../../vue.config');
export default {  
    data() {
        return {
            displayURL: ""
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("check 1")
        this.displayURL=vueconfig.VUE_APP_MyURL
        console.log(vueconfig.VUE_APP_MyURL)
        console.log("check 3")
    }
}
</script>
```

With vue.config looking like this:

```
module.exports = {
    VUE_APP_MyURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL
}
```

If I hardcode a value into VUE_APP_MyURL in the vue.config file it shows successfully on the helloworld page.

VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL is successfully populated with the correct value when I interrogate it: kubectl describe pod

process.env.VUE_APP_MyURL doesn't seem to successfully retrieve the value.

For what it is worth... I am able to use process.env.VUE_APP_3rdURL successfully to pass values into a Node.js app at runtime.

Comment: Ae you building the vue code into static html/js or running it as a `dev` in docker?

Comment: FWIW as long as you have access to the file containing the env variables, you may use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to parse it

Comment: Thanks @varcorb I'm building the vue code into static html/js

Comment: per the exact thing you are asking, Hendrik Malkows answer does this, and it was super useful that he detailed how to add it. Please consider marking it the correct answer! To be clear, i have a k8s configMap, that gets injected at runtime, and allows me to pass a base URL over the top of the one from process.env

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a file `config.js` with your desired configuration. We will use that later to create a config map that we deploy to Kubernetes. Put it into your your Vue.js project where your other JavaScript files are. Although we will exclude it later from minification, it is useful to have it there so that IDE tooling works with it.

```js
const config = (() => {
  return {
    "VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL": "...",
  };
})();
```

Now make sure that your script is excluded from minification. To do that, create a file vue.config.js with the following content that preserves our config file.

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /config.*config\.js$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'config.js'
              },
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In your index.html, add a script block to load the config file manually. Note that the config file won't be there as we just excluded it. Later, we will mount it from a `ConfigMap` into our container. In this example, we assume that we will mount it into the same directory as our HTML document.

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>config.js"></script>
```

Change your code to use our runtime config:

```js
this.displayURL = config.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL || process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL
```

In Kubernetes, create a config map that uses the content your config file. Of course, you wanna read the content from your config file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
data:
  config.js: |
    var config = (() => {
      return {
        "VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL": "...",
      };
    })();
```

Reference the config map in your deployment. This mounts the config map as a file into your container. The `mountPath` Already contains our minified index.html. We mount the config file that we referenced before.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: ...
      containers:
        - ...
          volumeMounts:
                - name: config-volume
                  mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/config.js
                  subPath: config.js
```

Now you can access the config file at `<Base URL>/config.js` and you should see the exact content that you put into the ConfigMap entry. Your HTML document loads that config map as it loads the rest of your minified Vue.js code. Voila!

Comment: where should I place the config.js and how to I import the config when I am using it in the code?

Comment: I just added some more detailed explanation. does it help?

Comment: @HendrikMHalkow Could you you add a `tree` of what your project structure looks like?

Comment: Hi, does this sulotion work if the `config` object needs to be referred in a Typescript file? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add some more detailed explanation or a link to a project structure how it looks, also what if I need to load the same flag into index.html?

Comment: I made a gist of what this looks like for `Quasar` and `Vue3`.

https://gist.github.com/nkreiger/f5d0ce20a98fb8e0161b4750f3bb4f46

Answer (score 27):

I am adding my **working solution** here, for those who are still having trouble. I do think that @Hendrik M Halkow 's answer is more elegant, though I couldn't manage to solve it using that, simply just because of my lack of expertise in webpack and Vue.I just couldn't figure out where to put the config file and how to refer it.

My approach is to make use of the environment variables with constants (dummy values) to build it for `production`, then replace that constants in the image using a custom `entrypoint` script. The solution goes like this.

I have encapsulated all configs into one file called `app.config.js`

```
export const clientId = process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID
export const baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL

export default {
  clientId,
  baseURL,
}
```

This is used in the project just by looking up the value from config file.

```
import { baseURL } from '@/app.config';
```

Then I am using standard **.env.[profile]** files to set environment variables. 
e.g. the `.env.development`

```
VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8085/radar-upload
VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID=test-client
```

Then for **production** I set **string constants** as values.
e.g. the `.env.production`

```
VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL
VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID=VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID
```

Please not here the value can be any unique string. Just to keep the readability easier, I am just replacing the environment variable name as the value. This will just get compiled and bundled similar to development mode.

In my `Dockerfile`, I add an `entrypoint` that can read those constants and replace it will environment variable values.

My **Dockerfile** looks like this (this is pretty standard)

```
FROM node:10.16.3-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:1.17.3-alpine

# add init script
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ .

COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# expose internal port:80 and run init.sh
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then create a **./docker/entrypoint.sh** file as below.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ROOT_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/html

# Replace env vars in JavaScript files
echo "Replacing env constants in JS"
for file in $ROOT_DIR/js/app.*.js* $ROOT_DIR/index.html $ROOT_DIR/precache-manifest*.js;
do
  echo "Processing $file ...";

  sed -i 's|VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL|'${VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL}'|g' $file 
  sed -i 's|VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID|'${VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID}'|g' $file

done

echo "Starting Nginx"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

This enables me to have runtime configurable image that I can run on many environments. I know it is a bit of a hack. But have seen many people do it this way.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hi @NehaM, I just added some more detailed explanation to my proposed solution. I hope it helps you. I recommend to avoid scripting your entry point as it doesn't work with distroless images. Have a look at https://github.com/SDA-SE/nginx – an NGINX image that is less than 6MB. If you can't avoid scripting, put an `exec` before the last command so that the shell process will be replaced by your nginx process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and improvising the answer. I am still using the solution I came up with. I have added small improvements to the code.

Comment: I think this one is the most elegant. I'd only like it to be more dynamic so we don't need to repeat the variables too much but not sure we can do this while staying readable

Comment: The value name should be different than the key name, otherwise it will not work.
In .env.production, it should be `VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL_value`

Comment: this is the best practice used by Gravitee.io frontend app, have a look at https://github.com/gravitee-io/gravitee-docker/blob/master/images/portal-ui/files/entrypoint.sh

Comment: Excellent and elegant solution!

Answer (score 11):

## Create config file

In public folder: [public/config.js](https://github.com/scholtz/covid-sk/blob/master/public/config.js)

```js
const config = (() => {
  return {
    "VUE_CONFIG_APP_API": "...",
  };
})();
```

## Update index.html

Update [public/index.html](https://github.com/scholtz/covid-sk/blob/master/public/index.html) to contain following at the end of head:

```html
  <!-- docker configurable variables -->
  <script src="<%= BASE_URL %>config.js"></script>
```

There is no need to update vue.config.js as we are using the public folder for configuration.

## ESLint

ESLint would give us error of usage of undefined variable. Therefore we define global variable in [.eslintrc.js](https://github.com/scholtz/covid-sk/blob/master/.eslintrc.js) file:

```js
  globals: {
    config: "readable",
  },
```

## Usage

Eg. in the store src/store/user.js

```js
export const actions = {
  async LoadUsers({ dispatch }) {
    return await dispatch(
      "axios/get",
      {
        url: config.VUE_CONFIG_APP_API + "User/List",
      },
      { root: true }
    );
  },
...
```

## K8S ConfigMap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fe-config
  namespace: ...
data:
  config.js: |
    var config = (() => {
      return {
        "VUE_CONFIG_APP_API": "...",
      };
    })();
```

## Deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: fe-config
      containers:
        - ...
          volumeMounts:
                - name: config-volume
                  mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/config.js
                  subPath: config.js
```

Comment: why not just define `const config = {xxx: "..."}` in config.js? thanks for your replay.

Comment: because config is hardcoded and you do not have option to modify it at runtime for example in kubernetes.. you have to load it post build

Comment: Thanks for your replay! My question is not so clear. I mean, why wrap object in an anonymous function and return it, why not just assigns an object to 'config'?

Comment: For deploying on multiple servers with different api endpoints this would be the best simple solution, no rebuild required for every servers, just change one line and go.

Comment: I tried this and got `ReferenceError: config is not defined` in `vue.config.js` when I tried `yarn serve`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in my current project and found out that it is not possible to access environment variables at runtime at the moment so I end up with the solution of creating .env files or local environment variables that, as you said, are used at the build time.

Comment: The author of this post explains that it doesn't make sense to try pass a variable into static html.js code. I finally get it! https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/8sbosc/how_to_access_environment_variables_passed_to_a/

Comment: build time not runtime .. is a violation of release engineering principles... Anyway, create-react-app is the best for React .. from that perspective

Answer (score 4):

If you are using VueJs3 + Vite3 + TypeScript, you can do this:

create **app.config.ts** (not JS)

```js
export const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID
export const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL

export default {
  clientId,
  baseURL,
}
```

Replace values in **assets** subdir: (improved shell script)

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185305/storing-bash-output-into-a-variable-using-eval
ROOT_DIR=/usr/share/nginx/html
          
# Replace env vars in JavaScript files
echo "Replacing env constants in JS"

keys="VITE_CLIENT_ID
VITE_API_BASE_URL"

for file in $ROOT_DIR/assets/index*.js* ;
do
  echo "Processing $file ...";
  for key in $keys
  do
    value=$(eval echo \$$key)
    echo "replace $key by $value"
    sed -i 's#'"$key"'#'"$value"'#g' $file
  done
done

echo "Starting Nginx"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

In the Dockerfile don't forget "RUN chmod u+x"

```bash
# build
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

then you be able to import it in any TypeScript file in the project

```js
import { baseURL } from '@/app.config';
```

@see update of NehaM response: [Pass environment variable into a Vue App at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime/57928031#57928031)

Comment: What is the index.js though? Is that the same as the index.html for me?

Comment: This is the file built, for example, VueJs+Vite will build in asset build dir : About.3ebd8e42.css,  About.a0fa1f22.js, index.a144206e.css and... index.47dd29d7.js

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a set of plugins to solve this problem elegantly:

- No global namespace pollution.
- No `import` statement is required.
- Almost zero configuration.
- Out-of-the-box support for Vue CLI (also works with Webpack, Rollup and Vite, CSR, SSR and SSG, and unit testing tools. Powered by Unplugin and Babel).

You can access environment variables (heavily inspired by Vite) this way:

```
// src/index.js
console.log(`Hello, ${import.meta.env.HELLO}.`);
```

During production, it will be temporarily replaced with a placeholder:

```
// dist/index.js
console.log(`Hello, ${"__import_meta_env_placeholder__".HELLO}.`);
```

Finally, you can use built-in script to replace placeholders with real environment variables in your system (e.g., read environment variables in your k8s pod):

```
// dist/index.js
console.log(`Hello, ${{ HELLO: "import-meta-env" }.HELLO}.`);
// > Hello, import-meta-env.
```

You can see more info at https://iendeavor.github.io/import-meta-env/ .

And there is a [Docker setup example](https://github.com/iendeavor/import-meta-env/tree/main/packages/examples/docker-starter-example#readme) and [Vue CLI setup example](https://github.com/iendeavor/import-meta-env/tree/main/packages/examples/%40vue%2Bcli%404-example#readme).

Hope this helps someone who needs this.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the solution proposed by @Hendrik M Halkow.

But I stored the config.js in the static folder. By doing that, I don't have to care about not minifying the file.

Then include it like this:

```
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>static/config.js"></script>
```

and use this volume mount configuration:

```
...
volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/static/config.js
      subPath: config.js
```