# Vuejs use environment variable in docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I have a vue.js app and I'm using .env to configure environment variables.

```
VUE_APP_API_LOCATION=http://localhost:8091
```

I also used Docker to build an image for the app: (taken from vuejs documentation)

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /my-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Finally, my objective is to distribute this app and to be able to configure these properties using docker-compose (this is what I have atm):

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  portal:
    restart: always
    build:
      # I use a dockerfile to specify the image
      context: my-app/
      args:
        FRONTEND_VERSION: $FRONTEND_VERSION
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      VUE_APP_API_LOCATION: my-remote-host:8091
```

So my problem is when I use the docker-compose vue is still using the .env property and pointing to localhost:8091 instead of the one specified in the environment.
I tried to print the variable inside of the container and it's the one specified in the docker-compose(my-remote-host:8091).

This is how I use the variable in my main.js:

```
Vue.prototype.$API_LOCATION = process.env.VUE_APP_API_LOCATION;
```

Any suggestion on why the app isn't using the one in docker-compose?
Thanks in advance

Comment: keep in mind that you have to rebuild the image everytime you restart container in order for changes to take effect. just executing ‘docker-compose up’ wont do anything, you need to ‘docker-compose up —build’

Comment: my point being, you maybe haven’t actually rebuilt the image with new env var, it happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass environment variable into a Vue App at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime)