# Getting environment variables at runtime in a compiled VueJS app

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I'm working on a VueJS app that uses env vars in multiple places. It runs on GCloud with nginx serving the files compiled with `vue-cli-service build`.

When developing everything works well with the env vars set in `.env.development` and `.env.development.local` files and used in JS with `process.env.VUE_APP_FOO`. I'm not using `.env.production` as some of these env vars shouldn't be committed to our repository.

For the staging and prod environment of all of our projects, we use GCloud's config maps which let us provide env vars to the pods. The issue in this project is that `vue-cli-service build` requires the env vars to be available at build time, which is not the case in our setup. Config maps are only available in the pods that run the images.

Out of curiosity, I checked the compiled code and all uses of `process.env` are quite simply replaced by an object with all vue env vars (basic ones + `VUE_APP_*` ones). So for example,

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_FOO);
```

is compiled to

```
console.log(Object({NODE_ENV: "production", BASE_URL: "/", VUE_APP_FOO: "bar"}).VUE_APP_FOO);
```

Except that in our case, `VUE_APP_FOO` is missing from the object as it's not available in the environment when building the app.

So as is, it doesn't seem possible to provide env vars when the server is started or the JS file is served. Is there a way to tell `vue-cli-service` to not compile the env that way? Or any other alternative?

The only one I found so far is to replace the uses of env vars with their actual value directly in the compiled JS file when the pod starts using `sed`, but that's pretty ugly and could break easily.

Comment: Yep, the docker image is build using Drone (compiled and then dist files copied to an image) and then pushed to GCloud.

Comment: Yep, but given our current setup this would require us to store the envs in a repo which we don't want to do. Also as mentioned in another comment below, this turns "env vars" into "build params" which kinda breaks our regular setup as well. Updating an env var should only require a pod restart, not a complete rebuild.

Comment: "How would a pod restart update the compiled resources which reference VUE_APP_FOO" => we have other projects referencing env vars (os.getenv in Python for example). Changing those only requires booting up a new container with the updated config map, no rebuild necessary. A typo in a URL or API key could occur even when building the project, it'd be more annoying if we had to go through a full rebuild instead of simply restarting the pods.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can follow is to provide the production values when building locally. Another approach is to setup a continuous integration workflow that fetches your environment variables from wherever it is stored, builds the apps and pushes to production servers. I personally work with approach 2.
It is relatively easy to setup a github workflow that runs whenever your code is pushed to a particlar branch

Comment: What bothers me is that these variables are really env vars and not really build parameters. Changing them should only require a container restart and not a full rebuild, which is how things work for our other projects. That is why I was looking for a "runtime" option.

Comment: You have a web app and not a server running. All env vars need to be bundled into the app at buildtime.. So when there is a change in any of them, there needs to be a complete rebuild

Comment: You cannot have a runtime option for a web app because the runtime environment is the user's browser. Now, you cannot set environmental variables in another user's computer, can you?

Comment: "All env vars need to be bundled into the app at buildtime..". Why would they? We have another website and an API where many variables are populated when the JS is being served. For example in rails ERB templates using `const foo = <%= Rails.appilcation.config.bar %>`, where `bar` is itself defined when the server starts based on environment variables.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby in rails, but I believe it should be a server side rendering solution. Building an application with a javascript framework like Vuejs usually includes the build process to bundle up everything required to run the application, so that it doesn't need to contact with a server got any information, apart from the static built files

Answer (score 0):

See the following answer from another Stack Overflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962511

They creating a config.js-file, which is changeable on runtime.