# How to get docker-compose "environment" variables with Vue.js?

Tags: docker, vue.js, variables, docker-compose, environment-variables

I currently have four environment variables inside an .env, all of which work correctly but declaring them inside docker-compose doesn't work. Is there any way to take these variables from the compose? I read that an nginx server should be used but I'm a bit confused.

This is what my docker-compose.yml currently looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6kcI.png)

Comment: Hello, maybe the answers to this question may be helpful to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime