# Webpack 5: Is it possible to output a javascript file non-bundled for configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a  React TypeScript project that uses webpack 5.

I am trying to get a `runtime-config.js` file that I can change out in production by importing it as decribed [in a similar Vuejs Docker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010064/pass-environment-variable-into-a-vue-app-at-runtime).

I wanted to use File Loader but found that it's been [deprecated in webpack 5](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Here's what I want to achieve:

- have `./runtime-config.js` non bundled so that I can refer to it on the window object
- easily reference that file in React (TypeScript) so that this dynamic configuration can be read.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my webpack configuration:

```js
// webpack.config.js

import path from 'path'
import { Configuration as WebpackConfiguration, DefinePlugin, NormalModuleReplacementPlugin } from 'webpack'
import { Configuration as WebpackDevServerConfiguration } from 'webpack-dev-server';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin'
import ESLintPlugin from 'eslint-webpack-plugin'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

interface Configuration extends WebpackConfiguration {
  devServer?: WebpackDevServerConfiguration;
}

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 4000,
    open: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx',
    'pdf.worker': path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // postcss loader needed for tailwindcss
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: '../fonts',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /runtime-config.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'runtime-config.js',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
    }),
    new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /^pdfjs-dist$/,
      (resource) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        resource.request = path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js')
      },
    ),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
      // relative path is from src
        { from: 'public/images', to: 'images' },
      ],
    }),
    // Add type checking on dev run
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
    }),
    // Environment Variable for Build Number - Done in NPM scripts
    new DefinePlugin({
      VERSION_NUMBER: JSON.stringify(process.env.VERSION_NUMBER || 'development'),
    }),
    // Add lint checking on dev run
    new ESLintPlugin({
      extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    }),
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};

export default config
```

Comment: Have you seen/tried the replacement for `file-loader`, ["asset modules"](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)? As described in the docs, type `asset/resource` "emits a separate file and exports the URL", and is a direct replacement for `file-loader`.

Comment: I did, here's my new config

```
{
  test: /runtime-config.(t|j)s$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
},
```
but I'm unable to load or see that file anywhere when I attempt to navigate it. Additionally I'm using typescript which also makes things a bit more complicated for importing a random JS file

Comment: Remember that asset modules are intended to be raw copies from source to destination, _if and only if you actually import the module_. Unlike normal JS/TS, you import the file to indicate that you want to include it, which triggers Webpack to copy the file at build time and _return the destination filename as the import_. None of this would compile a `runtime-config.ts` into a `runtime-config.js`, though: Assets don't go through the normal compilation and minification. If you want Webpack to do that for you you'll need a different method, such as giving runtime-config.js its own entry point.